# Do I need to embed a UINavigationController & Programmatically add UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I don't see all of my navigation bar.
There is only a outline of where a nav bar would be.
I set the navigationBar Color and tint colors so as to define this nav bar even if it had no items.

1. I used Storyboards to make the currently functional UI.
2. My Story Board UI includes Delegates,Custom Collection View Cells,Custom Table View Cells,And Animations.
3. By the end of my app I wanted to add nav bars programmatically to each of my ViewControllers. (see code)
4. I have used this code in 6 other classes. And I Have 6 Perfectly Flawless navigation bars in those ViewControllers.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];

   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizeralloc] 
      initWithTarget:self 
      action:@selector(titleGestureLabelMethod)];

       UILabel * titleView = [UILabel new];
             titleView.text = @"Title";
           titleView.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
           [titleView sizeToFit];
           titleView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
           [titleView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

            self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView; 
            [self.view addSubview:titleView]; 
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar   setTranslucent:NO]; 

   UIBarButtonItem *lButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"L"
    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
    target:sel
    action:@selector(lButtonMethod)];

   [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:lButton animated:YES];

   UIBarButtonItem *rButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"R"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                     target:self
                                     action:@selector(rButtonMethod)];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rButton animated:YES];

   self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor    greenColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:testTwoNavBar];


   }
   ```

Comment: You should clean up your question and edit any errors in typing, otherwise it's much more difficult to understand what you're asking and what you need.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with that, but you question is impossible to read. Please reformat it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed your view controller into a navigation controller. If you're using Interface Builder, from your storyboard select the view controller. In the menu select editor and choose embed in navigation controller. It's hard to understand what you really need though from this question.